# Strange cut behavior

Tags: cut, coreutils

I'm using `cut (GNU coreutils) 8.24`.

The command: `echo "TEST=test" | cut -d"=" -f2-` outputs `Ttest`. I don't think this is the intended behavior.

Am I using it wrong or is there something wrong with my `cut`?

Comment: With GNU coreutils 8.21 I get the expected behavior (just test).

Comment: impossible...works fine for me on centos 7, freebsd 10, debian 8 and solaris11...impossible

Comment: What O/S are you on? Also, worth pointing out that new versions of a piece of software can introduce new bugs; so `8.21` and `8.23` being fine doesn't necessarily mean his version, `8.24`, will be as well. That having been said, I'd be kind of surprised if someone managed to screw up `cut`.

Comment: Is it possible that some previous command (in your script) is outputting "T" (with no newline)?  e.g. `printf "%s" "T" ; echo "TEST=test" | cut -d"=" -f2-`

Comment: What happens if you `strace` the write() calls from the cut process?  `echo "TEST=test" | strace -e write cut -d"=" -f2-`

Comment: Or even just `ltrace`.

Comment: works correctly with Fedora and upstream coreutils 8.24 here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reproduction issues come down to the provider of libc. Namely, it seems like its a bug in uclibc; see: https://bugs.busybox.net/show_bug.cgi?id=4099

Under certain circumstances, cut prints the first character of field 1 and all of field 2 when told to print field 2 -- so for instance:

```
printf "4123\t2\t3\t4\t5\n" | cut -f 2
```

prints out 42; not just 2. I did run strace on that cut, and it did show that cut is printing the whole line.

The bug seems related to how it wants to treat lines without delimiters; so a work around for now is using the '-s' flag; like so:

```
printf "4123\t2\t3\t4\t5\n" | cut -f 2 -s
```

which prints '2', as expected.

I imagine most people running into this are using buildroot; and I'd recommend modifying uclibc's configuration as per that link. Mainly this just means:

```
make uclibc-menuconfig
Select y for 'String and Stdio Support --> Provide a macro version of [getc|putc]'
```

note that since this is changing the libc implementation; it is probably prudent to also rebuild basically everything.

Comment: Nice info thanks. Note doing the above is a good idea as it should be faster anyway.  Though technically it is only a workaround to the actual issue. I think this patch may fix the actual issue itself on all uClibc configs: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnulib/2015-12/msg00003.html